# How to save video in ios extension file like .mp4 .webm in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Am having bit a problem saving videos and i want to download it for sure if the video is downloaded and can be shown public in gallery or photos in ios.

code so far

```
final down = await getTemporaryDirectory(); // from path_provider
File saveFile = File(down.path +
             "/${mediaUrl.substring(mediaUrl.lastIndexOf("/")).replaceAll("/", "")}");

await DioMethods.d
              .download(response["url"].toString(), saveFile.path);
await GallerySaver.saveVideo(saveFile.path).then((value) =>
              Loadings.snackBarmessage(
                  title: mediaUrl
                      .substring(mediaUrl.lastIndexOf("/"))
                      .replaceAll("/", ""),
                  message: "Saved Successfully"));
```

error logs if the file is .webm

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): File on path is not a video.
```

Comment: Can you add some code snippets, that you've tried so far?

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana i edited the question with code so far

Answer (score 0):

If would like to view the files on your mobile, you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver) `gallery_saver plugin` to save your video file in `Gallery`.

```
final video = await controller.stopVideoRecording();
await GallerySaver.saveVideo(video.path);
```

Comment: Let me know if its not helpful!!

Comment: Its work on normal mp4 but when webm i always get errors then crashing the app. and also i edited my question